# Lossless Rice Compression

Tags: decryption

I am trying to figure out how the [Lossless Rice compression](http://www.firstpr.com.au/audiocomp/lossless/#rice) algorithm works on the following file. Here is a [DICOM file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/me8bcw).

Looking at the information I can see:

```
$ gdcmdump I160 | grep "Tamar Compression Type"
(07a1,1011) CS [LOSSLESS RICE ]                                # 14,1 Tamar Compression Type
```

I can open the image using [TomoVision](http://www.tomovision.com/download/binaries/Tomo_21_r5.zip). The image is 512x512, 16bits (unsigned).

The compressed stream:

```
$ gdcmraw -t 07a1,100a I160 comp.raw
```

contains (hexdump comp.raw):

```
1A D5 F8 EB  F2 77 A5 CE  A3 54 D5 2A  C0 5D AA 32...
```

But TomoVision seems to output a series of zeroes until byte 0x1DE. I can also use a command line tool: [DICOMatic](http://www.tomovision.com/download/download_dicomatic.htm) to process the file. However without a proper license, the [generated file](http://www.speedyshare.com/qhjq2/I160.dcm) contains a waterwark. So only the first few bytes looks ok:

```
$ gdcmraw /tmp/I160.dcm /tmp/pixeldata.raw
$ hexdump /tmp/pixeldata.raw |less
```

Some more encoded files can be found [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/4Xr9f/lossless-rice.tgz).

Comment: [this](http://sun.aei.polsl.pl/~rstaros/papers/ss2003-eh.pdf) looks related. Also, providing a non-RICE dicom and a non-graphical tool (unlike TomoVision) supporting the RICE-compressed file would help. ([5 years old](http://comp.compression.narkive.com/uIjbk5UE/reverse-engineering-variable-length-encoding-of-differences-of-predictions) ?)

Comment: You can edit the question and make changes. If you want to ask about specific aspects, or maybe try out a different approach, you can post another question. The only restriction being that it should be distinct enough to not warrant a close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not worth any bounty, but it might help, as `Tomovision.exe` doesn't look obfuscated in any way after a quick look, and contains the algorithm you're looking for:

1. open it in your favorite disassembler
2. check for reference to `RICE` strings (such as `C:\TomoVision\Prog\Prog_Lib\TomoVision_Convert\NEMA_Compression_RICE_decode.cpp` at address `4F59C4`)
3. study the ASM code - a.k.a. do your homework ;)